# OpenLayers 5 loads the WFS features but doesn't add and show them in the map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, web-feature-service

This should actually be very easy, but I've been stuck here for two days and still can't find a reason why OpenLayers doesn't do what I am expected from the API.

There is a WFS Layer I want to load and show in my map. The Capabilities can be seen here: http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/gis/aktuell/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

After going through the Capabilities, I started to build my VectorLayer. I have read from the Openlayers API that there are two ways to load the features: one is with **format** and **url**, another is with **loader**.

Since the **format + url** way seems very simple, I decided to use this. I created the URL based on what I got from the Capabilities:http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/gis/aktuell/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gk:waterlevels&outputFormat=GML3

As you can see, all 530 features in GML3 format can be loaded through this URL, so up until this stage there is no problem.

I started to write OpenLayers 5 code:

```
createVectorLayer () {
    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        name:"waterlevels",
        source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GML3(),
            url: "http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/gis/aktuell/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gk:waterlevels&outputFormat=GML3"
        }),
        style: new OlStyle({
            image: new Icon({
                src: 'static/Icons/waterlevels.png'
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I have done all the imports, but just not shown them here to save space.
The first thought was actually that the style seems not very good. But after I check the layers with `layer.getSource().getFeatures()` I find out there there are 0 features in the Vectorlayer.

But in the net analyse, I could see the GML file with 530 features successfully loaded. So I am a little bit confused right now.

I would appreciate if someone can point out which step I may be doing wrong here. I have already checked multiple times for imports, WFS Capabilities, and changed Styles also multiple times. I even tried with **loader**, But nothing works so far.

Comment: srsName is required option for the format `format: new GML3({ srsName: "urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" }),`

Comment: or just `srsName: 'EPSG:4326'` will also work